# Tried all the ways but can't reset my passwd

Tags: bash, mount, root, reboot, password-recovery

I have tried the sudo command, I have tried the init=bin/bash (or something like that - now I don't remember), I have tried the mount -o -n remount/ sw, and without the -o and everything that I have seen online. Anyways it doesn't work.

When I have tried in the root it doesn't show me letters, just figures of something similar to diamonds (idk) and I have notice that I can't write the letter 'm' there, I don't what is happening and of course I have no idea of how to solve it.

Also if nothings works I'am open to reboot ubuntu (18.04) but I have dual booting with Windows 7, if someone can tell how to do it the easiest way, please.

Thank you very much

Have a nice day

Comment: Do you have some keyboard layouts other than English?

Comment: @Kulfy I have Tibetan and Spanish but I changed English as the primary language and still doesn't work :(

Comment: Are you booting up in recovery mode and then running commands?  Are you referring [Jorge Castro's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/816190)?

Comment: Yes I did many times now, and yes I refered to his ansewer and many other :(

Comment: How did you changed English as your primary language?